# Fetching w/ custom React hook based on router parameters

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data with a custom React hook, based on the current router parameters.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fetch-router

### What it should do:

On first load, check if URL contains an ID...

- If it does, fetch a todo with that ID
- If it does not, fetch a todo with a random ID & add ID to url

On fetch button clicks...

- Fetch a todo with a random ID & add ID to url

### What is wrong:

Watching the console or inspector network tab, you can see that it's firing several fetch requests on each click - why is this and how should this be done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you used history.push on handleClick, you will see multiple requests being sent as you are using history.push on click handler which will cause a re-render and make use use random generated url as well as also trigger the fetchTodo function.

Now a re-render will occur which is cause a randomised id to be generated. and passed onto useTodo hook which will lead to the fetchTodo function being called again.

The correct solution for you is to set the random todo id param on handleClick and also avoid unnecessary url updates

```
const Todos = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const { id: todoId } = useParams();
    const { fetchTodo, todo, isFetching, error } = useTodo(todoId);
  const isInitialRender = useRef(true);

    const handleClick = () => {
    const todoId = randomMax(100);
    history.push(`/${todoId}`);
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        history.push(`/${todoId}`);
    }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isInitialRender.current) {
        fetchTodo();
    } else {
      isInitialRender.current = false
    }
  }, [todoId])

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleClick} style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>Fetch a todo</button>
        {isFetching ? (
          <p>Fetching...</p>
          ) : (
          <Todo todo={todo} color={todo.color} isFetching={isFetching} />
        )
      }
        </>
    );
};

export default Todos;
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fetch-router-uy6tgz?file=components/Todos.js)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still seeing multiple fetches on each load in your forked demo though?

Comment: Updated a working demo, instead of handling redirect in todo.js. we used a redirect from index.js